# Understanding Indexed Family of Sets using Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I am having a hard time comprehending what exactly the questions are asking. My thinking so far is that I am trying to find a family of subsets that satisfy the union and intersections of for example $x > n^2.$
So if i took $A_{1}$ I would get all real numbers greater than $1$ for the union, and for the intersection wouldn't it just be $\{\emptyset\}$ since as we go to infinity there will never be a set that has the same values?

If there are any resources online that I could read that would explain this or if someone can guide me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Work out $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ and $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n},$ where $A_{n}$ is defined as follows for $n \in \Bbb N.$

1. $A_{n}=\{ x\in \Bbb R \mid x > n^2 \}.$
2. $A_{n}=\{ x\in \Bbb R \mid \frac{1}{n^2}<x<\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{n}\}.$
3. $A_{n}=\{ x\in \Bbb R \mid -3n<x<\frac{1}{n^2}\}.$

Answer (score 0):

1. You are right: $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=(1,\infty)$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\emptyset$.
2. In this case, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\left(0,1+\sqrt2\right)$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\left(1,\sqrt2\,\right]$. Can you justify it?
3. In this case, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\left(-\infty,1\right)$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=(-3,0]$. Again, can you justify it?

Comment: when im trying to justify it, is it as simple as showing what is in $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ to perhaps see a pattern?

Comment: No. For instance, in the first case $A_1\supset A_n$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and therefore the union is $(1,\infty)(=A_1)$. And if $x\in\Bbb R$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\leqslant n^2$. So, $x\notin A_n$ and therefore it does not belong to the intersection.

Comment: Actually, in part 2 I believe the intersection is $(1, \sqrt 2)$.

Comment: @ChubbyChef I was wrong, but it seems to me that the answer is $\left(1,\sqrt2\,\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

The questions are asking for you to work out the unions $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup ... $ and intersections $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap ... $ of those infinite families of sets.
For example, in point 1 that'd be $ \{x \in \mathbb{R}| x>1\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}| x>2^2\} \cup ... $ and $\{x \in \mathbb{R}| x>1\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}| x>2^2\} \cap ... $ respectively. The union will be the set of all points in at least one of the sets and the intersection the set of points in all of them.

Comment: You should use either `\mid` or `|` for the middle line in set-builder notation. The slash makes it easier to misinterpret as being a quotient set. Compare $\{x\in\mathbb{R}/x\gt 2^2\}$, written with `\{x\in\mathbb{R}/x\gt 2^2\}`, with $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\gt 2^2\}$, produced with `\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\gt 2^2\}`.